# Certain parts of Python script not running

Tags: python-3.x

Under the choose option 2 part. If the input is bread the rest of that part won't run. The script just ends there. What is wrong can someone tell me? I don't get any error message the script just stops. Other than that everything works

```
bread = 44
lettuce = 21
meat = 21
cheese = 23
sandwich = bread, lettuce.meat, cheese

choseOption = input('What you like to mark an order, add to stock, or check stock')

if choseOption == 1:
    newOrder = input('what did they order?')
    if newOrder == 'sandwich':
        bread = bread - 4
        lettuce = lettuce - 5
        meat = meat - 7
        cheese = cheese - 10
        print(bread)
        print(lettuce)
        print(meat)
        print(cheese

if choseOption == 2:
    newStock = input('What would you like to add to stock?')
    if choseOption == 'bread':
        addBread = input('How much bread would you like to add? ')
        bread = bread + addBread

    if newStock == 'lettuce':
        addLetuce = input('How much lettuce would you like to add?')
        lettuce = lettuce + addLetuce

    if newStock == 'meat':
        addMeat = input('how much meat would you like to add?')
        meat = meat + addMeat

    if newStock == 'cheese':
        addCheese = input('how much cheese would you like to add?')
        cheese = cheese + addCheese

if choseOption == 3:
    viewItem = input('what item do you want to view?')

    if viewItem == 'bread':
        print(bread)

    if viewItem == 'lettuce':
        print(lettuce)

    if viewItem == 'meat':
        print(meat)

    if viewItem == 'cheese':
        print(cheese)
```

Comment: _"I keep getting error messages and I am clueless of what wrong."_  Have your tried looking at the error message and seeing what it says?

Comment: @john1024 yes It said the if chooseOption == 2: has invalid syntax but I don't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        print(cheese

if choseOption == 2:
```

Since `print(cheese` was not closed, `choseOption == 2:` was interpreted as part of the `print` command. Suggested code:

```
bread = 44
lettuce = 21
meat = 21
cheese = 23
sandwich = bread, lettuce.meat, cheese

choseOption = input('What you like to mark an order, add to stock, or check stock')

if choseOption == 1:
    newOrder = input('what did they order?')
    if newOrder == 'sandwich':
        bread = bread - 4
        lettuce = lettuce - 5
        meat = meat - 7
        cheese = cheese - 10
        print(bread)
        print(lettuce)
        print(meat)
        print(cheese)

if choseOption == 2:
    newStock = input('What would you like to add to stock?')
    if choseOption == 'bread':
        addBread = input('How much bread would you like to add? ')
        bread = bread + addBread

    if newStock == 'lettuce':
        addLetuce = input('How much lettuce would you like to add?')
        lettuce = lettuce + addLetuce

    if newStock == 'meat':
        addMeat = input('how much meat would you like to add?')
        meat = meat + addMeat

    if newStock == 'cheese':
        addCheese = input('how much cheese would you like to add?')
        cheese = cheese + addCheese

if choseOption == 3:
    viewItem = input('what item do you want to view?')

    if viewItem == 'bread':
        print(bread)

    if viewItem == 'lettuce':
        print(lettuce)

    if viewItem == 'meat':
        print(meat)

    if viewItem == 'cheese':
        print(cheese)
```

Comment: that helped but there is another problem. under if choose option == 2): if the input is bread the rest of that part won't run but everything else runs

Answer (score 2):

```
    print(cheese
```

needs a closing `)`